# Capture leads from facebook on salesforce org

Tags: leads, web2lead

Is there any app which could generate a lead with required fields in salesforce org when a person likes a page in facebook?

How do I get this done?

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/sbhanot-sfdc/Social-Web-to-Lead

Answer (score 4):

Make a small site from site.com in your own salesforce. Go to setup->app setup->develop->sites

You will get a URL from here that will go into the facebook app that you create. The app will diret the person to this site(much like it happens in IBIBO etc) and his/her information is sent to that site. The site's visualForcePage captures this information and converts it into a lead using standard controller...

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write a tool that connects **Facebook API** (to check if anyone new liked a post you're interested in) and then use one of the **Salesforce APIs** to create the SF-data you desire.

Facebook API:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/

Overview of Salesforce API:  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm&language=en_US