# Salesforce Lead Generation through Facebook ads

Tags: integration, leads, sales-cloud

I am currently using Facebook ads for my target audience in order to generate leads.
The leads are getting generated in a .csv file. Then i have to upload this data in my SFDC.
This requires a lot of manual processes which consumes a lot of time as well.

Is it a way to integrate Facebook ads with my SFDC so that my leads can directly be created inside salesforce and the whole process can be automated?

It would be a great help if anyone who is currently doing this can guide me.

I have gone through some 3rd party apps which can help in achieving the same but I don't want to rely on them since I am already spending a lot of money on my Facebook ad campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

In the Salesforce Product Portfolio, this is what Marketing Cloud's Advertising Studio is for (specifically, the Lead Capture feature) . Curiously enough my team has actually worked on a project where a client set up a Marketing Cloud *only* for this integration - you have to do your own math with the pricing, I guess. Here's the official documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ads_advertising_studio.htm&type=5

Comment: So, does it mean that this is not achievable with the sales cloud?

Comment: Cannot definitely exclude it, as I am not an SFSC expert, but the other posts on this site suggest the same. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/capture-leads-from-facebook-on-salesforce-org?rq=1  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289338/facebook-to-salesforce-sales-cloud-service-cloud-integration?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party tool called [Zapier](https://zapier.com/blog/create-salesforce-leads-facebook/). This is far the easiest way to configure this integration, as this can be done without need for any development. This of course comes with an ongoing cost for the tool, as well as (potentially) introducing another integration platform into your system landscape.

If you or your team have experience in development, you could explore the possibility of utilising [Facebook Webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/quickstart/webhooks-integration/) to pass the data to Salesforce. This will not only require you to create a custom Facebook app for calling the webhook, but also create such a webhook on Salesforce. There are few resources for the latter, here:

- https://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/30/create-webhooks-on-salesforce-com
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEknJb-j6gY
- https://salesforce-webhook-creator.herokuapp.com/

This approach is heavier, but will remove your dependency and cost of a 3rs party application as Zapier.